# How can I upload file using DRF in my own custom html template?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-templates

**models.py**

```
class Contents(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    formula = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, max_length=100)
    wiki = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100)
    youtube = models.CharField(null=True, max_length=100)
    file = models.FileField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**view.py**

```
class ContentsListCreateAPIView(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    template_name = 'admin3.html'
    style = {'template_pack': 'rest_framework/vertical/'}

    def get(self, request):
        queryset = Contents.objects.all()
        serializer = ContentsSerializer
        return Response({'serializer': serializer, 'contents': queryset, 'style': self.style})

    def post(self, request):
        queryset = Contents.objects.all()
        serializer = ContentsSerializer(data=request.data)
        print(serializer.is_valid())
        print(serializer.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return redirect('contents_list')
        return redirect('contents_list')
```

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Contents


class ContentsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Contents
        fields = '__all__'
```

**admin.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'contents_list' %}" method="POST">
               {% csrf_token %}
               {% render_form serializer %}
               <input type="submit" value="Save">
```

It seems that the filefield does not get the proper input. I don't get what the problem is. The CreateAPIView works well when I use the default DRF template.

Comment: Try adding `enctype='multipart/form-data'` to your `<form>` tag in the  HTML

Comment: god bless you! it immediately fixed the problem thank you so much